# Offline reading of posts in SO android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Sometimes, I really feel the need for having offline reading of posts ( Just like the Wikipedia's android app). Is it possible with SO in present release ? If not, can this be made as an improvement ?

Comment: Yeah, seems to be duplicate. But that one also not answered yet.

Comment: Indeed. Not implemented yet and nothing useful to say about it.

Comment: "*Yeah, seems to be duplicate. But that one also not answered yet*" Yeah, that can be frustrating, but it doesn't help having this question as well. Any answers should be on the other one, plus anyone coming here who can/will answer will just go to the other one. You can place a bounty on the other question, asking for an "official response", if your heart is truly in it :)